# Keep getting "Cannot Sign XDR" error message while trying to add assets

Tags: xdr

In a fully functional lobstr wallet with no issues, I signed out (on iPad) to look at another wallet and when I logged back into the first wallet, I could not add any assets or move assets between wallets because I kept getting "**Cannot sign XDR**" error message. I do not have the lobstr vault nor the Multisig enabled.

Also, after logging back in I had to input my password on each and every page in lobstr!

Basically my wallet is being held hostage by the error code and continual password check on each page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently hadsame issue I found if you request a password reset this will take care of the error.  You must wait 48 hours for them to email a link to reset it.  Once done you are able to do transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your phone app just reinstall app. Just happened to me. Fix worked. No more Sign XDR code.